# What do these vi commands do?

Tags: vi

The first one is:

```
.,+15s/first/second/g
```

I know that the . simply repeats the last operation but i'm not familiar with the rest of it. The other vi command I would like to know is:

```
10yy (followed by) p
```

Answer (score 3):

The first command replaces (`s`) all occurences (`g`) of `first` with `second` in the current (`.`) and the next 15 (`+15`) lines. It is supposed to be entered in `vim`'s command line, which can be opened using <kbd>:</kbd>. For more information about replacing, see the [vim wiki](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Search_and_replace).

The second command copies (`yy`) 10 lines, starting from the current one, then pastes (`p`) them below the current line.